# Subtle difference

Tags: differences

What is the difference between these sentences here :

''This is a clock.''    vs.
''It is a clock.''  ,
  or  in the same way: 
''It's an earring''  ,   and     ''This is an earring.''

Also,    ''What's this?''    vs.  ''What's it?''  .
And

How do you spell it?   vs.    How do you spell that?

[image]

Comment: On the face of it, you're just using alternate words. What's your deeper question?

Comment: The sentences about the earrings are responses to questions, the ones about the clocks are free-standing statements. The _it's_ and _they_ are pronouns which need context to have meaning but _this_ and _these_ indicate the object without explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Rule of thumb:

- Use *it* (or plural *they*) only when you are speaking about something which has already been introduced into your discourse and is 'current'—playing a role in the discourse at the time you speak.

  > I bet you're wondering how I knew 'bout your plans ... I heard ***it*** through the grapevine.
  >
  > *(announcing a birth)* ***It***'s a girl!
- Use *this* (or *that*, or plural *these/those*)

  - when you are introducing something new into the discourse, (or reintroducing something which has fallen out of currency):

    > Today we have naming of parts ... ***This*** is the lower sling swivel. And ***this*** is the upper sling swivel, whose use you will see, when you are given your slings.
  - when you need to distinguish one entity from others in the discourse:

    > That's not a knife. ***This*** is a knife. *(But this line qualifies under both criteria.)*